# Python incorrect call() behaviour while calling svn di

Tags: python, svn, subprocess

I call

```
'svn di -revision <revNumber>:HEAD --summarize --xml >>svndiff.xml'
```

through subprocess.call(), and I get an error

```
svn: E020024: Error resolving case of '>>svndiff.xml'
```

If I type the same command into terminal, it works fine.
Where is a trap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the terminal, `>>svndiff.xml` gets interpreted by the shell. When using `subprocess.call` in the default mode, such an argument gets passed to the `svn` process literally. (You didn't show the actual `subprocess.call` invocation, but given the error message, that's the most likely diagnosis.)

Instead, you must use the `stderr` keyword argument to provide suitable output. For example:

```
with open('svndiff.xml', 'a') as log:
    subprocess.call(["svn", "di", "--revision", "%s:head" % rev_number,
                     "--summarize", "--xml"], stdout=log)
```

or, you can use `shell=True` to have the shell do it for you (with the usual pitfalls of shell parsing such as problems with file names containing spaces and shell injection):

```
subprocess.call("svn di --revision %s:HEAD --summarize --xml >>svndiff.xml" % rev_number,
                shell=True)
```